# Reading googledrive contents from R

Tags: r

I'm aiming to get a list of all files in a Google Drive folder, as well at the associated metadata for those files. When I use drive_ls, it returns 3 columns {name, id, drive_resource}. drive_resource is a structured like this: list(kind = "drive#file", id = "abc",...). However, some of the list is not qualified by quotations, and commas are also occassionally used when not a separator.

Any ideas how I might properly unlist this? I can't find anywhere in the package that can handle this.

Using the package 'googledrive', I can get a list of all the files

```
a <- drive_ls(path = "abc", recursive = TRUE)
```

The below attempt gets close, but fails to get thee column names and also splits some values at the wrong place based on a comma being contained in the string.

```
a$drive_resource <- vapply(a$drive_resource, paste, collapse = ",", character(1L))

abcd <- a%>% separate(drive_resource, sep = ",", into = c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30") )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach. It's an example with only four elements of the list (selected names are specified in the function). The function maps each list contained in each row to a tibble, so you can unnest it

```
require(googledrive)
require(dplyr)

f <- function(l){
  l[c("version","webContentLink","viewedByMeTime","mimeType")] %>% as_tibble()
}

dr_content <- drive_ls(path = "<path>", recursive = TRUE) 

dr_content <- dr_content %>% mutate(drive_resource = purrr::map(drive_resource, f))

dr_content <- dr_content %>% tidyr::unnest(drive_resource)
```